# Compare two cells in different worksheets, set different cell as ok

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub test1()

Dim Str As String
Dim Search As String
Dim Status As String
Str = Cells(2, 5).Value
Search = FDSA!Cells(2, 5).Value
Status = FDSA!Cells(2, 10).Value

    If InStr(Search, Str) = True Then
                Status = "ok"
    Else
         End If

End Sub
```

I will be building up from this with loops. I want to check if what is in Cells(2,5) is contained in FDSA!Cells(2,5). If it is true then I would like to mark FDSA!Cells(2,10) as ok. I am getting an object required message. This is what I could come up with after looking at examples and tutorials. Let me know if you have questions

Only second time working on VBA.
Thanks in advance, Alexis M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax for referencing the worksheet is incorrect.  That is probably throwing the error.  You need to call to `Worksheets("FDSA")` and not use the `FDSA!` call like you have.

Also, you will have to set the cell value equal to `Status` for this to work.  Just changing `Status` will not write it back into the workbook.

Also `InStr` returns the location of the match.  If you want to know if there was a match, you need to check that the return is `>0`.  This code should run and hopefully is closer to correct than your current code.

```
Sub test1()

Dim Str As String
Dim Search As String

Str = Cells(2, 5).Value
Search = Worksheets("FDSA").Cells(2, 5).Value


    If InStr(Search, Str) > 0 Then
        Worksheets("FDSA").Cells(2, 10).Value = "ok"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this has done what I have asked for. Have a good day!